# Ignite service start failed but ansible task does not fails

Tags: linux, ansible, ignite, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to write `ansible`(version 2.6.17) playbook to install `ignite`(2.7.6) in a linux server as a `systemd` service.

The playbook run completes without failure.

```
    PLAY [install ignite in servers]
    ************************************************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] 
    *************************************************************************************
    ok: [ignitehost1]

    TASK [ignite/install : download and unarchive ignite binaries] 
    **********************************************************************************************
    changed: [ignitehost1]

    TASK [ignite/install : copy config file] 
    *****************************************************************************************
    changed: [ignitehost1]

    TASK [ignite/install : include_tasks]  
    *******************************************************************************
    included: /home/platform/ignite/ansible-ignite/roles/ignite/install/tasks/systemd.yml for 
    ignitehost1

    TASK [ignite/install : install ignite.service] 
    ************************************************************************
    changed: [ignitehost1] => (item={u'd': u'/etc/systemd/system', u'f': u'ignite.service'})

    TASK [ignite/install : systemctl daemon-reload] 
    *****************************************************
    ok: [ignitehost1]

    TASK [ignite/install : start ignite] 
    ******************************************************************************
    changed: [ignitehost1]

    TASK [ignite/install : check if ignite has started] 
    *****************************************************************************
    changed: [ignitehost1]

    PLAY RECAP 
    ***********************************************************
    ignitehost1               : ok=8    changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But my ignite start has failed with known reasons. As you can see in the output of the ignite service 
status provided below , the main process exited with SUCCESS status which I guess is the reason why my playbook run was successful .**Is there any way possible to fail my playbook run if there are any error while starting my service.**

```
sudo systemctl status ignite
? ignite.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ignite.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2020-03-16 16:10:32 IST; 12min ago
Process: 28938 ExecStart=/home/platform/ignite/tmp/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/bin/ignite.sh 
(code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 28938 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1 Ignite[28938]: at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:962)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: at 
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: ... 1 more
Mar 16 16:10:32 ignitehost1  Ignite[28938]: Failed to start grid: Cannot write to work directory: 
/home/platform/ignite/tmp/apache-ig...in/work
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Below is my task file to start ignite.

```
    ---
    - name: install ignite.service
       become: yes
       become_user: root
       with_items:
        - f: ignite.service
          d: /etc/systemd/system
      template:
        src: '{{ item.f }}.j2'
        dest: '{{ item.d }}/{{ item.f }}'
        mode: '{{ item.m|default("0644") }}'
      register: ignite_service_installed

    - name: systemctl daemon-reload
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      systemd:
        daemon_reload: yes

    - name: start ignite
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      service:
        name: ignite
        enabled: yes
        state: started
```

Below given is the system unit template file for ignite service

```
    Description=Apache Ignite Service
    After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   WorkingDirectory="{{installation_dir}}/apache-ignite-{{ignite_version}}-bin"
   User=platform
   PrivateDevices=yes
   ProtectSystem=full
   ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
   KillMode=mixed
   KillSignal=SIGTERM
   TimeoutStopSec=10
   ExecStart="{{installation_dir}}/apache-ignite-{{ignite_version}}-bin/bin/ignite.sh"
   SyslogIdentifier=Ignite
   Restart=on-failure
   RestartSec=5

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  Alias=ignite.service
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ansible will check the return codes of commands. This default behaviour can be changed using error handling techniques.

Ansible provides `failed_when` conditional to allow us to define what “failure” means.

Read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am aware of the ansible error handling mechanism.But I was wondering if it can be  managed by systend unit file itself?